# keyboard-setup.service taking too long in startup (20+sec)

Tags: boot, gnome, keyboard, startup, services

so I'm trying to improve my startup time now 41.772s (using UBUNTU 17.04/GNOME 3)

I have solved some problems but I can't seem to find a solution to improve keyboard-setup.service

systemd-analyze blame:

```
20.671s dev-sda6.device
     20.294s keyboard-setup.service
     16.885s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     15.296s systemd-sysctl.service
     10.730s networking.service
      9.848s ntp.service
      6.699s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.546s click-system-hooks.service
      5.229s ModemManager.service
      4.989s accounts-daemon.service
      4.741s NetworkManager.service
      4.343s grub-common.service
      3.740s iio-sensor-proxy.service
      2.926s repowerd.service
      2.102s systemd-modules-load.service
      2.043s colord.service
      1.847s fwupd.service
      1.770s upower.service
      1.529s switcheroo-control.service
      1.372s user@128.service
      1.357s polkit.service
      1.322s irqbalance.service
      1.167s systemd-rfkill.service
```

systemd-analyze critical-chain:

```
graphical.target @36.002s
 └─multi-user.target @36.002s
  └─systemd-resolved.service @34.741s +363ms
    └─network.target @34.733s
      └─wpa_supplicant.service @30.369s +679ms
    └─basic.target @24.005s
      └─sockets.target @24.004s
        └─snapd.socket @23.986s +16ms
          └─sysinit.target @23.928s
            └─apparmor.service @23.387s +538ms
              └─local-fs.target @23.384s
                └─run-user-128.mount @35.104s
                  └─local-fs-pre.target @23.384s
                    └─keyboard-setup.service @3.089s +20.294s
                      └─systemd-journald.socket @3.049s
                        └─-.slice @2.602s
```

Any help? Can I disable it and make the service start after boot? or should I install another keyboard driver?
My computer is a hp pavillion dv6 Intel i7, 8GB RAM

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've managed to decrease dramatically the keyboard-setup.service from 20 secs to 2 secs.
`gedit /lib/systemd/system/keyboard-setup.service`, and adding `TimeoutStartSec=10sec` at the bottom of `[Service]`. I am still battling with `systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service`

Comment: I used @Jeroen Vermeulen - MageHost 's method below (`sudo systemctl edit ...`) and in fact did it for `systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service` too. Now, it reduced the keyboard-setup by 6s to 16s (still very high) and reduced the tmpfiles-setup from ~20s down to >1s. On Kubuntu 18.04, I have a USB keyboard, and USB isn't enabled in my "BIOS" (I made a mistake, have to reset it to enable); both/either of those might be pertinent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@hector-muñoz-h's answer works, but it is not the right way. You should not edit distro files.

This is the right way:

```
FIXSERVICE="keyboard-setup.service"
mkdir -p "/etc/systemd/system/${FIXSERVICE}.d"
echo -e "[Service]\nTimeoutStartSec=10" > "/etc/systemd/system/${FIXSERVICE}.d/reduce-timeout.conf"
```

You can also use `systemctl edit keyboard-setup.service` and paste in the editor:

```
[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=10
```

Then save & quit the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to decrease dramatically the keyboard-setup.service from 20 secs to 2 secs. 
`sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system/keyboard-setup.service`,

and adding the line:

`TimeoutStartSec=10sec`

after the last line of [Service] bit.
Turns out my problem was that this service was going to timeout and this had not been defined.