# How to speed up boot time on lubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu, systemd

New to linux and ubuntu.
I have shared my laptop info. Boot up time is sooooo slowwwww.
Even lauch of firefox takes long time.

Can anyone help me figure out how to optimize my system?

Using Lubuntu (Ubuntu Version)

Command

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Command

```
$ sudo lshw -short
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         Aspire A515-51G (0000000000000000)
/0                          bus            Charmander_KL
/0/0                        memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60
/0/4/5                      memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                      memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                      memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/d                        memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/d/0                      memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffer
/0/d/1                      memory         [empty]
/0/100                      bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processo
/0/100/2                    display        UHD Graphics 620
/0/100/14                   bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Control
/0/100/14/0      usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/5               communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
/0/100/14/0/7               multimedia     HD WebCam
/0/100/14/1      usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/15                   generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Contro
/0/100/15.1                 generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Contro
/0/100/16                   communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                   storage        Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHC
/0/100/1c                   bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Por
/0/100/1c/0                 display        GP108M [GeForce MX150]
/0/100/1c.4                 bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Por
/0/100/1c.4/0               generic        RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.4/0.1  enp2s0f1   network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit
/0/100/1c.5                 bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Por
/0/100/1c.5/0    wlp3s0     network        Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone 
/0/100/1f                   bridge         Intel(R) 100 Series Chipset Family LP
/0/100/1f.2                 memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
/0/1             scsi0      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0       /dev/sda   disk           1TB WDC WD10SPZX-21Z
/0/1/0.0.0/1     /dev/sda1  volume         927GiB EXT4 volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2  volume         3970MiB Extended partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2/5   /dev/sda5  volume         3970MiB Linux swap volume
```

Used this command

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 6.870s
└─multi-user.target @1min 6.870s
  └─kerneloops.service @1min 6.842s +26ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 6.836s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @58.305s +8.529s
        └─NetworkManager.service @48.794s +9.507s
          └─dbus.service @48.775s
            └─basic.target @48.690s
              └─sockets.target @48.690s
                └─snapd.socket @48.620s +69ms
                  └─sysinit.target @48.618s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @48.458s +159ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @47.215s +1.185s
                        └─systemd-journal-flush.service @5.764s +41.448s
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.325s +1.438s
                            └─systemd-journald.socket @4.229s
                              └─system.slice @4.229s
                                └─-.slice @4.170s
```

Saw this post
[Can we talk about the boot time on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8dws67/can_we_talk_about_the_boot_time_on_ubuntu_1804/)

Ran

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 4.907s (kernel) + 7min 8.181s (userspace) = 7min 13.089s
graphical.target reached after 1min 6.870s in userspace
```

Ran

```
$ service --status-all | grep '+' | wc -l
27
```

Answer (score 3):

**1. Journal size limit**

The time consuming `systemd-journal-flush.service` can be tweaked by a journal size limit.
Edit the Journal config file

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/journald.conf

# uncomment and configure the value
SystemMaxUse=50M
# personnaly i use 2M ;)

# Then restart the journald service
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

**1.1 Journal clean up**

```
sudo journalctl --rotate
sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s
```

For information, the journal size is given by this command:

```
journalctl --disk-usage
```

**2. Startup applications**

Another step to speed up userspace load delay is to disable some startup applications
See how to show all of them : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ShowHiddenStartupApplications

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

See how to open the Startup Applications applet : https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html

```
 gnome-session-properties
```

If you dont mind, disabling `Backup Monitor` and `Updates Notifier` will save boot time.
[image]

Comment: `SystemMaxUse=` 1 Min 27 Sec, `SystemMaxUse=5M` 1 Min 24 Sec and `SystemMaxUse=50M` 1 Min 24 Sec

Comment: did #1. No startup apps I can nuke (only have lidclose). Startup finished in 4.889s (firmware) + 445ms (loader) + 2.018s (kernel) + 2.751s (userspace) = 10.105s. graphical.target reached after 2.746s in userspace. Better on g.t so me happy :) :) +1!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [cmak.fr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156317/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-on-lubuntu?#answer-1156336)

I looked into [What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service?#answer-1094543)

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/journald.conf
```

In the journal section uncomment and alter:

```
Storage=auto
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
SystemMaxFiles=5
```

Save & reboot.

[keyboard-setup.service taking too long in startup (20+sec)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919428/keyboard-setup-service-taking-too-long-in-startup-20sec?#answer-920858)

```
sudo gedit /lib/systemd/system/keyboard-setup.service
```

changed

```
TimeoutStartSec=10sec
```

[Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot?#answer-615429)

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

edit from 30 to 15

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=30
```

[Long boot times on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029050/long-boot-times-on-18-04?#answer-1029534)

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @59.292s
└─multi-user.target @59.291s
  └─kerneloops.service @59.278s +12ms
    └─network-online.target @59.277s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @52.596s +6.681s
        └─NetworkManager.service @45.820s +6.773s
          └─dbus.service @45.792s
            └─basic.target @45.790s
              └─sockets.target @45.790s
                └─snapd.socket @45.745s +44ms
                  └─sysinit.target @45.743s
                    └─swap.target @45.543s
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f01c80a9\x2d4d4b\x2d4e60\x2dbeb0\x2d
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f01c80a9\x2d4d4b\x2d4e60\x2dbeb0\x
```

and

```
$ systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 4.770s (kernel) + 59.301s (userspace) = 1min 4.072s
graphical.target reached after 59.292s in userspace
```

From `7min 13.089s` to `1min 4.072s` a huge improvement, if anyone has any more improvements that I am not aware of please do share.

Comment: Mind adding what the hardware specs are? make, model. cpu and harddisk should be enough. I have a HP omen with SSD as boot. Startup finished in 4.734s (firmware) + 454ms (loader) + 2.071s (kernel) + 2.998s (userspace) = 10.258s. Now  adding your tweaks. Be right back :D

Comment: That got bad D: Startup finished in 5.863s (firmware) + 471ms (loader) + 2.080s (kernel) + 17.499s (userspace) = 25.916s  graphical.target reached after 2.732s in userspace. Hmmm :P

Comment: ah! the software updater was the cause.  Startup finished in 4.751s (firmware) + 453ms (loader) + 1.955s (kernel) + 2.793s (userspace) = 9.953s 
graphical.target reached after 2.788s in userspace. I LOVE YOU :=D  Keyboard did not have a delay in it so only the other 2 used.

Comment: Your `dev-disk-by` entries are truncated and we can't see the time they are taking up.

Comment: @Rinzwind [Acer Aspire 5](https://paytmmall.com/aspire-5-nx-gt1si-001-core-i5-8250u-nvidia-geforce-mx150-CMPLXLAPASPIRE-5-NX-DUMM2025628B250D2-pdp?product_id=155780600)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my contribution to this little **Show & Tell**:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2.490s
└─multi-user.target @2.489s
  └─snapd.service @1min 34.450s +153ms
    └─basic.target @2.227s
      └─sockets.target @2.226s
        └─snapd.socket @2.205s +13ms
          └─sysinit.target @2.197s
            └─systemd-update-utmp.service @2.136s +54ms
              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @2.116s +9ms
                └─local-fs.target @2.108s
                  └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 26.644s
                    └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 25.977s
                      └─local-fs-pre.target @192ms
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @172ms +10ms
                          └─systemd-fsck-root.service @110ms +39ms
                            └─systemd-fsckd.socket @109ms
                              └─-.slice @81ms
```

Compare this **2.49 seconds** to [SDC's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1161303/307523) of **59.29 seconds** which has extra time consuming features I've removed from my boot-up:

```
  └─kerneloops.service @59.278s +12ms
    └─network-online.target @59.277s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @52.596s +6.681s
        └─NetworkManager.service @45.820s +6.773s
          └─dbus.service @45.792s
                └─snapd.socket @45.745s +44ms
                    └─swap.target @45.543s
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f01c80a9\x2d4d4b\x2d4e60\x2dbeb0\x2d
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f01c80a9\x2d4d4b\x2d4e60\x2dbeb0\x
```

Key features:

- [Remove Network Manager Wait](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009999/slow-boot-time-on-ubuntu-17-10-1-systemd-analyze-blame-results/1010024#1010024) from startup.
- [Remove snapd Refresh Service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958838/ubuntu-16-04-3-still-takes-1-5-minutes-to-boot-after-successful-clone-to-ssd-a/958850#958850) from startup.

---

### Systemd Journal Control enhancements

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See journald.conf(5) for details.

[Journal]
#Storage=auto
# Aug 4 2018 - recommended: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html
storage=persistent
```

The notable details are in **bold**.

Because `journalctl` files are not longer flushed at startup I have them setup to be **vacuumed** once a month:

- [Systemd logs (`journalctl`) are too large and slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012912/systemd-logs-journalctl-are-too-large-and-slow/1012913#1012913)

Often I want to know what happened when the system crashed and I had to reboot. By default `journalctl` files don't show you the previous boots though. So I turned on multi-boot history:

- [How do I find which Kernel Version I booted 2 weeks ago?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025348/how-do-i-find-which-kernel-version-i-booted-2-weeks-ago/1025349#1025349)

That's all for today. I'll try to remember to update this answer going forward.

Comment: `systemctl list-dependencies graphical.target` list few services including `multi-user.target`, this in turn has `100` services as `list-dependencies`   both taking same time `59.292s` will investigate further on how i can reduce these as well in my free time